# How to calculate the number of mappers/reducers in order to maximise the performance of mahout RecommenderJob running on Amazon cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mahout, reducers, mapper

What is the best way to calculate the right number of hadoop mappers and reducers to use, depending on the instances used/available on Amazon Elastic MapReduce ? (using RecommenderJob of mahout-core-0.7 distribution)

Answer (score 1):

The generic Hadoop answer applies:

- Let Hadoop pick the number of mappers
- Set the number of reducers equal to the number of reduce slots in your cluster

For EMR, look up the number of reducers that are run by default on the instance type that you're using: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HadoopMemoryDefault_AMI2.3.html

Then multiply by the number of workers you are using. That's a pretty ideal number of reducers -- or a small multiple of it even.

Until you have a specific reason to think these aren't optimal, I'd go with this.

*PS Don't forget to use spot instances for your workers to save money and/or deploy more workers.*

*Ad break*: if you are interested in Mahout, and recommendations, and running on EMR, you should probably be looking at [Myrrix](http://myrrix.com). I'm the founder, and also the author of some of the Mahout code you're running now. This is a "next-gen" Hadoop-based recommender product that, among other things, is already well optimized for EMR.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the fast answer. Well actually im trying to compare the user-baser and item-based recommendation algorithms on the cloud.If i let hadoop decide the number of mappers how can i find out how many are in use? and finally is there any user-based recommendation algorithm that i can directly run on amazon, like RecommenderJob? Thanks a lot

Comment: On Amazon EMR, if you open port 9100 and 9101 on the master machine, you can just browse to the raw Hadoop console. You can view anything you want about any job including number of mappers. I think you can get this from the logs too; enable the "Enable Debug Logging" step in EMR and it will expose a lot of logs through the console. There is not a user-similarity-based recommender for Hadoop, no.

Comment: What is the default training/test percentage that the RecommenderJob is using on the dataset? and how can i change it?

Comment: RecommenderJob is not doing any eval; no data is held out as a test set.

Comment: which other configuration of RecommenderJob beside the number of reducers will make a difference to the performance(speed)? Thanks

Comment: For this job? Not much *in Hadoop*. It's a kind of faked Hadoop-style job that's running in memory. You check your # of reducers and make sure you're not running out of memory. There is loads you can configure about the underlying recommender. If you're serious about recs on Hadoop I would not use this code. It's kind of a demo, not a serious implementation.